# React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Code:

```
export const HomePage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const refContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState<number>(0);
  const { current: elContainer } = refContainer;
  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    if (elContainer) setScrollY(elContainer.scrollTop);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [handleScroll]);
  return (
    <div className="pageScreen overflow-scroll" ref={refContainer}>
      <Works scrollY={scrollY} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

ScrollY state doesn't change, because elContainer is null. How can i fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what your does component do and what is the expected behavior ?

Comment: I need scroll value of div like window.scrollY to pass it to the component.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `useCallback` memoizes the scroll handler, causing it to reference a stale value of `elContainer`, particularly when it was `null` on the initial render.

Additionally, an element's `scrollTop` only changes when the element's content itself is scrolled, not the whole document. As a result, the `scroll` event handler should be attached to the `div`, allowing you greatly simplify your code, like so:

```js
export const HomePage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState<number>(0);
  
  const handleScroll = (evt) => setScrollY(evt.currentTarget.scrollTop);

  return (
    <div className="pageScreen overflow-scroll" onScroll={handleScroll}>
      <Works scrollY={scrollY} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Just note that for the event to work, the `div` itself needs to be able scroll, not the document, so you also need to style your `div` with `overflow: auto` and a `max-height`.

Here is a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dust-3qsbvn?file=/src/styles.css) of this in action.

Comment: Putting `elContainer` in the dependency array is not a reliable solution, because changes to a ref will not cause a rerender. So the first suggestion will only work if something causes HomePage to rerender, and thus a new handleScroll can be created. If the page only renders once, it will have the same problem as before.

Comment: @NicholasTower Good catch, I confused it with the behavior of `useEffect`. I will fix my answer

Comment: After that i got  scrollY == 0.

Comment: @iufb What exactly are you trying to achieve? [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) refers the vertical scroll amount of the element's content, which if the element doesn't scroll itself will always be 0. Do you mean to use `getBoundingClientRect().top`?

Comment: @DennisKats I need window.scrollY behavior but for div. Do you know good way to do that?

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you do want to use `scrollTop`. However, as I mentioned, an element's `scrollTop` only changes if the element's content itself is scrolled, not the whole document. As a result, you also need to attach the scroll event handler on the element, not the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { current: elContainer } = refContainer;
```

You are extracting the `.current` property from the ref during the very first render, and saving it in a variable `elContainer`. This value is null, because nothing is on the page yet. And since you only set up the scroll event once, handle scroll is forever using this null value.

Instead, don't access `.current` until handleScroll is called. That way, the first render will already be complete, and refContainer.current will have been mutated to have the element:

```
  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    const { current: elContainer } = refContainer; // Moved this inside the function
    if (elContainer) setScrollY(elContainer.scrollTop);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
    import { FC, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

    export const HomePage: FC = () => {
      const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0)
      const refContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

      const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
        if (refContainer.current) {
          setScrollY(-refContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect().y)
        }
      }, [])

      useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
        }
      }, [handleScroll])

      return (
        <div className="pageScreen overflow-scroll" ref={refContainer}>
          <Works scrollY={scrollY} />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Overall, the proposed code is more concise, easier to read, and more reliable. It uses the `FC` type to define the component, which is a shorthand for `FunctionComponent`. It uses the `getBoundingClientRect` method to get the scroll position, which is more accurate than using `scrollTop`. And it uses `document.removeEventListener` to remove the event listener on unmount, which is more specific and less prone to errors.